# Django save image from url and connect with ImageField

Tags: django, django-models

I have in `models.py`:

```
class Item(models.Model):
    image_file = models.ImageField(upload_to='images')
    image_url = models.URLField()
```

I want django automatically download and locally save image from `image_url` and "connect" it with `image_file`

**How it should act:**

1. I Paste `https://docs.djangoproject.com/s/img/site/hdr_logo.gif`
   into `image_url` field in admin
2. Click "save"
3. In templates write `<img src="{{ item.image_file.url }}">`. It shows
   image from my server, not `djangoproject.com`

**What I've tried:**

I've overwritten `save` method of `Item` class. I saved image locally via `urllib`, but I am stuck on connecting this saved image with `image_file` field

Answer (score 50, accepted):

```
from django.core.files import File
import os

class Item(models.Model):
    image_file = models.ImageField(upload_to='images')
    image_url = models.URLField()

...

def get_remote_image(self):
    if self.image_url and not self.image_file:
        result = urllib.urlretrieve(self.image_url)
        self.image_file.save(
                os.path.basename(self.image_url),
                File(open(result[0]))
                )
        self.save()
```

You can override the default save() method to automatically invoke get_remote_image().

See: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/db/models/#overriding-model-methods

Comment: How do you set the image's file name?

Comment: Python3 update: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17960942/attributeerror-module-object-has-no-attribute-urlretrieve

Comment: I am getting AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'save' when doing article.featured_image.save(name, ContentFile(response.content), save=True). have any idea why ? article is instance .

Answer (score 14):

```
from django.db import models
from django.core.files import File
from urllib.request import urlopen
from tempfile import NamedTemporaryFile

class Item(models.Model):
    image_file = models.ImageField(upload_to='images')
    image_url = models.URLField()

...

def get_remote_image(self):
    if self.image_url and not self.image_file:
        img_temp = NamedTemporaryFile(delete=True)
        img_temp.write(urlopen(self.image_url).read())
        img_temp.flush()
        self.image_file.save(f"image_{self.pk}", File(img_temp))
    self.save()
```

This solution avoid any utf-8 errors received during url process.

It works only with python 3.6+ because the f string.

Check this link: https://twigstechtips.blogspot.com/2012/04/django-programmatically-saving-image.html

Answer (score 11):

## For python3

```
from django.core.files import File
from urllib import request
import os

class Item(models.Model):
    image_file = models.ImageField(upload_to='images')
    image_url = models.URLField()

...

def get_remote_image(self):
    if self.image_url and not self.image_file:
        result = request.urlretrieve(self.image_url)
        self.image_file.save(
                os.path.basename(self.image_url),
                File(open(result[0], 'rb'))
                )
        self.save()
```

from here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17960942/attributeerror-module-object-has-no-attribute-urlretrieve

Comment: This seems to work for me where others don't, when uploading to my Backblaze B2 storage bucket.

Answer (score 7):

**Python3**

```py
from django.db import models
from django.core.files import File
from urllib.request import urlopen
from tempfile import NamedTemporaryFile

class Item(models.Model):
    image_file = models.ImageField(upload_to='images')
    image_url = models.URLField()

    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
        if self.image_url and not self.image_file:
            img_temp = NamedTemporaryFile(delete=True)
            img_temp.write(urlopen(self.image_url).read())
            img_temp.flush()
            self.image_file.save(f"image_{self.pk}", File(img_temp))
        super(Item, self).save(*args, **kwargs)
```

It`s similar but with automated save 'image_file', when add 'image_url'