# Trying to download a file by URL with urllib.retrieve: 'module' object has no attribute 'retrieve'

Tags: python, python-3.x

This is my first ever Python script, so I assume I'm doing something wrong. But I can't find a clue in any of the tutorials or examples. The following code (so to speak):

```
import urllib

urllib.retrieve("http://zlib.net/zlib-1.2.8.tar.gz")
```

throws an error

> AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'retrieve'

How do I fix it? This is Python 3.3.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7243750/download-file-from-web-in-python-3

Comment: @Sudipta: got it. I needed `import urllib.request` and not just `urllib`. Wanna make that an answer?

Comment: No point answering it again here, as it's already answered.

Comment: @Sudipta: I disagree.

Comment: Hey, I added it as an answer.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'urlretrieve'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17960942/attributeerror-module-object-has-no-attribute-urlretrieve)

Answer (score 14, accepted):

[The question was solved in the comments, hence adding it as an answer now.]

The below code works. (Source : [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7244263/952112))

```
import urllib.request
# Download the file from `url` and save it locally under `file_name`:
urllib.request.urlretrieve(url, file_name)
```

Note the import statement.

You need to do `import urllib.request` instead of `import urllib`.

Answer (score 4):

As the error says, `urllib` does not have a `retrieve` function.

In Python 2, the module did have a **`urlretrieve`** function. In Python 3, that function has been moved to `urllib.request.urlretrieve`.

You can find all this in the documentation: https://docs.python.org/3/library/urllib.html

Comment: Still no luck. `AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'request'`

Comment: Are you sure you're using Python 3?

Comment: Pretty sure: `Python 3.3.2 (v3.3.2:d047928ae3f6, May 16 2013, 00:06:53) [MSC v.1600 64 bit (AM
D64)] on win32
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>>`

Comment: Do you have a local script named "urllib.py"?

Comment: In the Python folder?

Comment: In wherever you're starting Python from.

Comment: No, I thought it's part of the standard library!

Comment: It is. If you had a local script, that would be found first, and would hide the stdlib one.

Comment: Ah! No, the folder is free of any other .py files.

Comment: I do have a file `c:\Python33\Lib\urllib\request.py` in my Python installation folder. Perhaps, there's some setup code missing from my script? The two lines I specified in the Q is literally all the contents of my .py file.

Comment: We want to make sure if Python 3 is being used by your script or not. Do this: Add `import sys; print sys.version` these lines on top your .py file, to check if it is indeed python 3

Comment: @Sudipta: that won't run due to missing braces. `print(sys.version)` does run and prints this: `3.3.2 (v3.3.2:d047928ae3f6, May 16 2013, 00:06:53) [MSC v.1600 64 bit (AMD64)]`