# NameError: name 'request' is not defined in python 3

Tags: python, python-3.x, urlretrieve

I am trying to run the basic feature extraction code from the following site:
[musicinformationretrieval](http://musicinformationretrieval.com/).
When I try to run the following code line:

```
kick_filepaths, snare_filepaths = stanford_mir.download_samples(collection="drum_samples_train")
```

it shows the following error message:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
AttributeError                            Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-3-7c764e7836ee> in <module>()
----> 1 kick_filepaths, snare_filepaths = stanford_mir.download_samples(collection="drum_samples_train")

C:\Users\dell\Desktop\stanford-mir-gh-pages\stanford_mir.py in download_samples(collection, download)
     89                 for i in range(1, 11):
     90                     filename = '%s_%02d.wav' % (drum_type, i)
---> 91                     urllib.urlretrieve('http://audio.musicinformationretrieval.com/drum_samples/%s' % filename,
     92                                        filename=os.path.join(collection, filename))
     93         kick_filepaths = [os.path.join(collection, 'kick_%02d.wav' % i) for i in range(1, 11)]

AttributeError: module 'urllib' has no attribute 'urlretrieve'
```

Please help me to solve this issue.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems you should use Python 2 insteed of 3. In [instruction](https://github.com/stevetjoa/stanford-mir#install-python-and-relevant-libraries) to stanford_mir there is line:

> 1. If you’re totally new, the simplest solution is to download and install [Anaconda for Python 2 (2.7)](https://www.continuum.io/downloads), not Python 3.

Also you can read why it is not working on Python 3 [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17960942/attributeerror-module-object-has-no-attribute-urlretrieve).

UPD:

for using Python 3 you can try add code before using the lib:

```
import sys

if sys.version_info[0] >= 3:
    from urllib.request import urlretrieve
else:
    # Not Python 3 - today, it is most likely to be Python 2
    # But note that this might need an update when Python 4
    # might be around one day
    from urllib import urlretrieve
```

UPD2:
urlretrieve import does not help)

Comment: so how this line will change for Python 3: urllib.urlretrieve('http://audio.musicinformationretrieval.com/drum_samples/test/%s' % filename, filename=os.path.join(collection, filename))

Comment: in best way you should not change it, because this is external lib, which should work with Python 2, just use Python 2. Also as I get already link to stackoverflow discussion about changes in urllib between Python's version, there is a suggetion to try... will add code to ansewer.

Comment: Ok. I'll install Python 2. The code update you have made is not working for me. I have tried already. Thanks for the help.