# AttributeError: module 'urllib3' has no attribute 'urlretrieve'

Tags: python, urllib, text-mining

I'm trying the code in [this link](https://github.com/adventuresinML/adventures-in-ml-code/blob/master/keras_word2vec.py) for doing word2vec by keras.

I receive error on this line:

```
filename, _ = urllib.urlretrieve(url + filename, filename)
```

the error is:

> AttributeError: module 'urllib' has no attribute 'urlretrieve'

for solving it I installed and imported urllib3 and change that line to:

```
filename, _ = urllib3.urlretrieve(url + filename, filename)
```

but I receive again with that error:

> AttributeError: module 'urllib3' has no attribute 'urlretrieve'

How can I fix it?

Comment: urllib.request.urlretrieve - https://docs.python.org/3.4/library/urllib.request.html#urllib.request.urlretrieve

Comment: this works :) Thank you so much.

Comment: Please refer to this link it has the solution to your problem. [click here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17960942/attributeerror-module-object-has-no-attribute-urlretrieve)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Extending from comments section:

As stated by documentation, you can access urlretrieve like this

```
urllib.request.urlretrieve
```

https://docs.python.org/3.4/library/urllib.request.html#urllib.request.urlretrieve

Answer (score 1):

The answer above is good enough, just want to remind that, if you get error

**module 'urllib' has no attribute 'request'**,

just try **import urllib.request** , I use python 3.7

```
import urllib.request

urllib.request.urlretrieve(url);
```