# trying to display the image that got extracted from the user posted link

Tags: python, django

This is what I'm trying to do. Let user post url, the url is submitted and extract main image from the link user posted. Display that image. I;m at a point the image got extracted as the user posted link(thank you for fixing the error) now I'm simply trying to display the image

```
Media.py
import json import urllib2 from urllib2 import Request from goose import Goose
def get_content(url):
    """This function is intended to return content from url.
    :param url: URL to get content
    :return: The response from url
    """
    req = urllib2.Request(url, headers={'User-Agent': "Magic Browser"})
    response = urllib2.Request.urlopen(req).read()
    return response 


def extract(url):
    url = get_content(url)
    g = Goose()
    article = g.extract(url=url)
    resposne = {'image':article.top_image.src}
    return json.dumps(resposne)

views.py



    class PostCreateView(CreateView):

         model = Post
         form_class = PostForm
         template_name = 'main/add_post.html'

         def form_valid(self, form):
                self.object = form.save(commit=False)
                # any manual settings go here
                self.object.moderator = self.request.user
                url = self.request.GET.get('url')
                image = extract(url)
                self.object.save()
                return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse('post', args=[self.object.slug]))

         @method_decorator(login_required)
         def dispatch(self, request, *args, **kwargs):

                return super(PostCreateView, self).dispatch(request, *args, **kwargs)

def index(request):
        categories = Category.objects.all()

        try:
                sort = request.GET["sort"].strip()
                sort_method = SortMethods[sort]
                page = request.GET["page"].strip()
        except KeyError:
                sort_method = SortMethods.score
                page = 1

        if sort_method == SortMethods.date:
                thread_list = Post.objects.order_by("-pub_date")
        else:
                thread_list = Post.objects.all()
                thread_list = sorted(thread_list, key=lambda x: x.get_score(), reverse=True)

        paginator = Paginator(thread_list, 30)

        try:
                posts = paginator.page(page)
        except PageNotAnInteger:
                posts = paginator.page(1)
        except EmptyPage:
                posts = paginator.page(paginator.num_pages)

        context = {
                "posts": posts,
                "pages": paginator.page_range,
                "sort": sort_method.name,
                "categories":categories,

        }
        return render(request, "main/index.html", context)


Models.py 

    class Post(models.Model):
        category = models.ForeignKey(Category)
        pub_date = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add = True)
        title = models.CharField(max_length = 100)
        content = FroalaField()
        url = models.URLField(max_length=250, blank=True, null=True)
        moderator = models.ForeignKey(User)
        rank_score = models.FloatField(default= 1)

        views = models.IntegerField(default=0)
        image = models.ImageField(upload_to="images",blank=True, null=True)
        slug = models.CharField(max_length=100, unique=True)

        objects = models.Manager()   


forms.py

class PostForm(forms.ModelForm):
    title = forms.CharField(max_length=128, help_text="plz enter")

    url = forms.URLField(max_length=200,
                         help_text="Please enter the URL of the page.", required=False)
    views = forms.IntegerField(widget=forms.HiddenInput(), initial=0)
    content = forms.CharField(widget=FroalaEditor)
    class Meta:
        model = Post

        exclude = ['pub_date', 'moderator', 'rank_score', 'image','slug']
```

Answer (score 1):

I don't see your models.py file. So I would do this:

1. Make sure, that you have in your models.py in your class a "column" e.g.

   img = models.FileField(upload_to='static/**your_directory**/', null=True)

   Without "null=True" Django cannot make migrations.
2. After submitting Django will place that image into mentioned directory.
3. Render image in your template after setting context data:

   <img src="/{{ **your_object**.img }}"> !!! do NOT forget the SLASH !!!

This is a setup without AJAX. Please read comments below for futher information, thx.

Comment: why does it have -1?I appreciate your answer. I'll post my models.py

Comment: I'm not trying to save the images tho, I just want them to be displayed

Comment: Yay, sorry, english is not my mother lang. The codes above I use regularly for displaying images from databases. So I hoped it could help.

Comment: it's ok, that's not what I was looking for tho. can you please help me? this is what I'm looking for, http://gooseextractor-t20.rhcloud.com/ when user posts url, the image is extracted and that image is displayed on index.html

Comment: Yea, finally get it. There is used an AJAX technology in my opinion. If I do this myself, I would use in form action="blablabla". Blalala is an URL (some function in views), which parse that image within posted URL > send the image to database > load the image from database via AJAX (no refreshing) and render it below "Extract" button. This would be my procedure, but there may be different ways to this, who knows? (I don't)

Comment: hmmm I'm not sure I get what you are saying. do you mind showing them with the code I have?

Comment: By action="blabla" I meant in template <form method="x" action="some_url">. If a user click on a submit button, a request will be send to Django w/ the data from that form. Django calls an appropriate function. Inside the function you should validate the form and get the image and save it to a database. From database load the image as JSON and render it. (All of this inside 1 function). Next, on that page, where the user posted a URL you should disable via javascript default behavior (refresh page) and via AJAX (jQuery) load the JSON mentioned before and place it below the extract button.

Comment: But I'm not experienced with AJAX, so I cannot help you with that :(

Comment: I'm struggling this for two days, this is my approach http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34476029/image-not-shown-updetail-in-context .....do you mind checking this out/ ?

Comment: I don't have enough reputation points for commeting your new question. Let's start with this: Do you see an image in the "images/" directory?