# Django ImageField widget that accepts upload or external link as source

Tags: python, django, django-widget, imagefield

Is there a Django widget for ImageFields that provides the option to either upload an image or provide a url?

I'm thinking like Summernote does (if you click the image icon) in [its examples](http://summernote.org/examples/)

I've browsed through many [apps](https://djangopackages.org/grids/g/photos/) and they are all focused on just uploading and thumbnailing.

***EDIT***

Still working on trying to do be able to do this.  I'm looking for something like the way django-summernote allows you to add images.

Also taking a look at this question about saving an image link into an ImageField.  How can I get both to work together ina  widget like Summernote?

[Django save image from url and connect with ImageField](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16381241/django-save-image-from-url-and-connect-with-imagefield)

Answer (score 4):

ImageFields based on FileField and can save only path to file with current media backend.

For save image from external url you should get link in separately form field and download this picture in tmp file and save to ImageFields.

Comment: DJango-summernote has an image widget that does this.

Comment: widget - it's not field.
You can download image form url for save to ImageFields  or simple save url to charfield or textfield

Comment: Of course, but I'm looking for a widget that can handle both =)

Comment: Your answer is only relevant to the default widget.

Answer (score 0):

No.  This widget does not yet exist.  You should make it.